# CodeEval Hard Challenge 6 - LONGEST COMMON SUBSEQUENCE - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to solve the [Longest Common Subsequence](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/6/) in Python. I've completed it and it's working fine although I've submitted it and it says it's 50% partially completed. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any help is appreciated.

**CHALLENGE DESCRIPTION:**

You are given two sequences. Write a program to determine the longest common subsequence between the two strings (each string can have a maximum length of 50 characters). NOTE: This subsequence need not be contiguous. The input file may contain empty lines, these need to be ignored.

**INPUT SAMPLE:**

The first argument will be a path to a filename that contains two strings per line, semicolon delimited. You can assume that there is only one unique subsequence per test case. E.g.:

```
XMJYAUZ;MZJAWXU
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE:**

The longest common subsequence. Ensure that there are no trailing empty spaces on each line you print. E.g.:

```
MJAU
```

My code is

```
# LONGEST COMMON SUBSEQUENCE
import argparse


def get_longest_common_subsequence(strings):
    # here we will store the subsequence list
    subsequences_list = list()

    # split the strings in 2 different variables and limit them to 50 characters
    first = strings[0]
    second = strings[1]

    startpos = 0
    # we need to start from each index in the first string so we can find the longest subsequence
    # therefore we do a loop with the length of the first string, incrementing the start every time
    for start in range(len(first)):
        # here we will store the current subsequence
        subsequence = ''

        # store the index of the found character
        idx = -1

        # loop through all the characters in the first string, starting at the 'start' position
        for i in first[start:50]:
            # search for the current character in the second string
            pos = second[0:50].find(i)

            # if the character was found and is in the correct sequence add it to the subsequence and update the index
            if pos > idx:
                subsequence += i
                idx = pos

        # if we have a subsequence, add it to the subsequences list
        if len(subsequence) > 0:
            subsequences_list.append(subsequence)

        # increment the start
        startpos += 1

    # sort the list of subsequences with the longest at the top
    subsequences_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

    # return the longest subsequence
    return subsequences_list[0]


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # read file as the first argument
    with open(args.filename) as f:
        # loop through each line
        for line in f:
            # if the line is empty it means it's not valid. otherwise print the common subsequence
            if line.strip() not in ['\n', '\r\n', '']:
                strings = line.replace('\n', '').split(';')
                if len(strings[0]) > 50 or len(strings[1]) > 50:
                    break
                print get_longest_common_subsequence(strings)

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The longest common subsequence is not `MJAU` its `XMJAUZ`

Comment: Not really, that's not a sequence. The example is given in the challenge description, it's not my result.

Comment: This is not clear then. Given the pair: `XMJYAUZ;MZJAWXU`  you said the longest common subsequence is `MJAU` and you also said: "This subsequence need NOT BE CONTIGUOUS". This is incorrect because `X` is also common, as well as `Z`. In fact, `MJAU` is also not contiguous subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution prints unordered/unsorted longest common subsequences/substrings from semi-colon-separated string pairs. If a string from the pair is longer than 50 characters, then the pair is skipped (its not difficult to trim it to length 50 if that is desired).

Note: if sorting/ordering is desired it can be implemented (either alphabetic order, or sort by the order of the first string or sort by the order of the second string.

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line and ';' in line and len(line) <= 101:
            a, b = line.split(';')
            a = set(a.strip())
            b = set(b.strip())
            common = a & b  # intersection
            if common:
                print ''.join(common)
```

Also note: If the substrings have internal common whitespace (ie `ABC DE; ZM YCA`) then it will be part of the output because it will not be stripped. If that is not desired then you can replace the line `a = set(a.strip())` with `a = {char for char in a if char.strip()}` and likewise for `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lcs_recursive(xlist,ylist):
    if not xlist or not ylist:
        return []
    x,xs,y,ys, = xlist[0],xlist[1:],ylist[0],ylist[1:]
    if x == y:
        return [x] + lcs_recursive(xs,ys)
    else:
        return max(lcs_recursive(xlist,ys),lcs_recursive(xs,ylist),key=len)



s1 = 'XMJYAUZ'
s2 = 'MZJAWXU'

print (lcs_recursive(s1,s2))
```

This will give the correct answer MJAU and X & Z are not part of the answer because they are sequential (Note:- Subsequent)

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!